# Как считать только первые 10 строк файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как считать первые 10 строк файла и записать их в переменную `lines`, с которой я потом буду работать. В целом такую же операцию я планирую проводить и с последними 10-ю строками.

```
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6]
t2 = lines [-5]
t3 = lines [-6]
```

Когда я делаю так:

```
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines (1,10)  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6]
t2 = lines [-6]
t3 = lines [-5]
```

PYCharm ругается следующим образом:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/АБИ/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/УрСО.py", line 10, in <module>
lines = f.readlines (1,10)  # читаем его построчно
TypeError: readlines expected at most 1 argument, got 2
```

Когда пользуюсь конструкцией:

```
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines1 = f.readlines()[:17]
lines2 = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines2 [6]
t2 = lines2 [-6]
t3 = lines2 [-5]
```

выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/АБИ/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/УрСО.py", line 12, in <module>
    t1 = lines2 [6]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У `readlines` нет таких опций. Можно через `for ie, line in enumerate(f): if e == 10: break`

Comment: `f.readlines (1,10)` -> `f.readlines()[:10]`

Comment: Тоже вариант, забыл)))

Comment: вариант с f.readlines()[:10] не сработал

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Вариант 1:

```
N = 10
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [next(f) for x in range(N)]
```

### Вариант 2:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(...) as f:
    lines = list(islice(f, 0, N))
```

**NOTE:** оба варианта прочитают только N первых строк файла и остановятся на этом. Т.е. файл не будет читаться полностью в отличие от варианта с `file.readlines()`

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что lines тут переменная? И как тогда тогда мне прочитать с последней до -10? N =-10?

Comment: @PallNick, да, это имя переменной - списка со строками

Comment: попробовал задать N=-10 и в результате получил пустую строку, подскажите, как можно считать первым способом строки снизу

Comment: @PallNick, с конца читать сложнее. Здесь есть несколько вариантов: https://stackoverflow.com/q/136168/5741205

Answer (score 0):

Если читать документацию, то там явно написано:
*The readlines() method returns **a list containing each line in the file** as a list item.*

Что непонятно? Этот метод читает ВЕСЬ файл, и ваши первые 10 и ваши последние 10 и все остальные.

Хотите построчно -  используйте метод readline().

Хотите прочитать ТОЛЬКО последние записи - используйте seek()

Хотите прочитать ВЕСЬ файл в обратном порядке

```
for line in reversed(list(open("filename"))):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: интересно а как можно использовать `file.seek()` для того, чтобы почитать только последние СТРОКИ?

Comment: Согласен, это можно сделать, если заранее знать длину строки.